# Mongoose find User with certain blog

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, router, mern

I have collection of Users and collection of Blogs. Blogs are nested inside User in array:

```
_id: "23030023030420aff",
occasions: [
           "ab95848gkdi011ff",
           "ab958493480311fd",
           "ab04399idif0430g"
           ],
           ...
```

How can i mongoose query search the user who owns one Blog by blog id for example "ab95848gkdi011ff"?

Answer (score 0):

If your User schema contain blogs array then you can Use query like below

```
User.find(blogs:{$in:["ab95848gkdi011ff"]}).populate({path:"blogs"})
```